# Using Plink to execute command within another command/shell

Tags: command-line, plink

My question is regarding the way the file ("-m" switch) is used by Plink.

My command is:

```
plink.exe -ssh admin@10.20.30.1 -pw p@ss30rd -m commandfile.txt
```

I'm trying to connect to a switch and execute these 3 commands:

```
system-view
user-interface vty 0
screen-length 200
```

The issue here, is that each command depends on it's predecessor. In other word, executing the command `system-view` gives access to a new level or a context where the second command `user-interface vty 0` can be valid and executed and same thing for the third command in which is only valid (and available) only if `user-interface vty 0` is executed

Is there a way or a workaround that we can achieve this using Plink?

My goal here is to put the "Plink" command line in a script and try to analyse the output

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify multiple commands using the `-m` switch, they are executed one *after* another. While you (if I understand you correctly) want to execute the commands *within* each other. That's not possible with the `-m` switch.

What you can do, is to feed the commands to Plink using an input redirection. This way, Plink behaves, just as, if you typed those commands.

```
(
    echo system-view
    echo user-interface vty 0
    echo screen-length 200
) | plink.exe -ssh admin@10.20.30.1 -pw p@ss30rd
```

Note that by default, with the `-m` switch, Plink does not allocate a pseudo terminal, while with the input redirection, it does. So the behavior is not identical. You can use the [`-t`/`-T` switches](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) to override that.